# Regex replace all character except last 5 character and whitespace with plus sign

Tags: javascript, regex

I wanted to replace all characters except its last 5 character and the whitespace with +

```
var str = "HFGR56 GGKDJ JGGHG JGJGIR"
var returnstr = str.replace(/\d+(?=\d{4})/, '+');
```

the result should be "++++++ ++++ +++++ JGJGIR" but in the above code I don't know how to exclude whitespace

Comment: Are you sure you're asking about C#? This looks more like JavaScript to me.

Comment: @TimPietzcker sorry about that. yes its javascript

Comment: If there's always at least 2 words, another idea to [search for `\w(\W+\w+$)?` and replace with `+$1`](https://regex101.com/r/s72jtb/1/)

Answer (score 3):

You need to match each character individually, and you need to allow a match only if more than six characters of that type follow.

I'm assuming that you want to replace alphanumeric characters. Those can be matched by `\w`. All other characters will be matched by `\W`.

This gives us:

```
returnstr = str.replace(/\w(?=(?:\W*\w){6})/g, "+");
```

Test it [live on regex101.com](https://regex101.com/r/os0fMD/1).

Answer (score 2):

The pattern `\d+(?=\d{4})` does not match in the example string as is matches 1+ digits asserting what is on the right are 4 digits.

Another option is to match the space and 5+ word characters till the end of the string or match a single word character in group 1 using an [alternation](https://www.regular-expressions.info/alternation.html).

In the callback of [replace](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace), return a `+` if you have matched group 1, else return the match.

`\w{5,}$|(\w)`

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/cDc8HP/1)

```js
let pattern = / \w{5,}$|(\w)/g;
let str = "HFGR56 GGKDJ JGGHG JGJGIR"
  .replace(pattern, (m, g1) => g1 ? '+' : m);
console.log(str);
```

Answer (score 1):

Another way is to replace a group at a time where the number of `+`
replaced is based on the length of the characters matched:

```js
var target = "HFGR56 GGKDJ JGGHG JGJGIR";

var target = target.replace(
        /(\S+)(?!$|\S)/g, 
        function( m, g1 )
        {
          var len = parseInt( g1.length ) + 1;
          //return "+".repeat( len );     // Non-IE (quick)
          return Array( len ).join("+");  // IE (slow)
        } );
        
console.log ( target );
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use negative lookahead with string end anchor.

```
\w(?!\w{0,5}$)
```

Match any word character which is not followed by `0 to 5` characters and end of string.

```js
var str = "HFGR56 GGKDJ JGGHG JGJGIR"
var returnstr = str.replace(/\w(?!\w{0,5}$)/g, '+');

console.log(returnstr)
```